# How to display elements of different post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, taxonomy, exclude

What happens is:

I have a custom post type called **"placas"** and have an associated custom taxonomy called **"firmas"** and this **taxonomy** is the terms **"LG", "AOC", "Panavox".**

I want to show a certain category post slider and exclude others.

What I did was use the following well **WP_Query** object. And I could exclude the term **"LG"** and show all the other

```
$arg = array (
'post_type' => 'placas',
'orderby' => 'rand',

'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'firmas',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array( 'LG' ),
        'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
    ),
   )
  );

  $query_slider= new WP_Query($arg);
?>
```

### The Problem:

I created a regular post type category called **"News"**. I need that post associated with the category News displayed on the slider.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your conditions but I think you want something like this:

```
$arg = array (
  'post_type' => array('post','placas'),
  'orderby' => 'rand',

  'tax_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'OR',
     array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'firmas',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array( 'LG' ),
        'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
     ),
     array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array( 'news' ),
        'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
     ),
   )
);

$query_slider= new WP_Query($arg);
```

You are including both relevant posts types in the query and you are altering your `tax_query` to return from either of two tax/slug combinations.

That brings me back to not being sure I understand your conditions. Depending on what you need, this may not work. You may need logic that `WP_Query` is not capable of, in which case you'd need one or more filters.

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum, very close to what I wanted, I served a lot of guidance, I needed was included and not excluded. 
Thanks, sorry for the delay in responding

Comment: Is this solved then? I can't tell.

Comment: This is an old answer, but ... From my recent experience: `relation` in this answer must be left to the default `AND`. I can't explain this, just an observation.